# MySQL resource in Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I'm starting a new project built on Zend Framework. I know all about controllers, layouts and views. But I don't know how to add a MySQL resource.

Basically, I would like to have some model classes with getters and setters and for each, a resource class witch would handle MySQL queries. These resources classes need access to a DB class which performs the actual queries. The configuration for the DB would have to be in a separate file somewhere as either XML data, .ini or PHP array.

How can I obtain that? Where should I put each the files (right now, I have the default Zend directory structure)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need to create an instace of connection to database ,Zend does it automatically..just add these following to your config file

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true;
resources.db.params.host = "yourserver"
resources.db.params.username = "username"
resources.db.params.password = "pwd"
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"
```

Comment: And how do I use it afterwards?

Comment: $obj = new YourModelClass();
$q = $obj->getAdapter->query(sql);
$q->execute or $q->fetch() //depends on ur need

Comment: And for the pure Zend way if you want to fetch all recors with id > 10
public somefunction(){
$select = $this->select();
$select->from($this,array('*'))
->where('id > ?',10);
return $this->fetchAll($select);

}

Answer (score 1):

you can use it later

```
$DB = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend comes with a set of DB classes that you can use.  Documentation is here:  http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html  Before asking questions like this please do a bit of Googling.

Comment: I already read the Zend documentation. I know how to use Zend_Db_Adapter, for example, but that still doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: If you follow the [ZF Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) they show the steps for configuring your database in application.ini and how to create classes and mappers for database access.  They use sqlite in the quickstart, but thanks to Zend_Db and its adapters, that doesn't change anything in your code.  All you need to do is configure the adapter in application.ini for pdo_mysql and the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
[general]
db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
db.params.host = server
db.params.username = username
db.params.password = password
db.params.dbname =   dbname

$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(ROOT_DIR.'/application/config.ini', 'general');
$DB = Zend_Db::factory($config->db);
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($DB);

$DB = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
```